# How to use extension properties in Kotlin as constants?

Tags: spring, nhibernate, kotlin, data-class

I have data class

```
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        val userId: Long = 0,

        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        val email: String = "",

        @Column(nullable = false)
        val firstName: String = "",
)
```

I hate using "" for initialization. I would like use something like

```
 @Column(nullable = false)
 val firstName: String = String.EMPTY
```

I know about extension properties or functions, but they looks aren't so good as well

```
val firstName: String = "".empty()
val firstName: String = "".EMPTY
```

How do you write entity classes? Is there more elegant way?

Comment: Why not use a const val instead? Reads well, but compiler inlines the value. 

`const val EMPTY_STRING = ""` in a file wherever makes sense, and have `val email: String = EMPTY_STRING.

Comment: How is the "nhibernate" tag relevant here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to use `String.EMPTY`, you can create an extension property on `String`'s companion object:

```
val String.Companion.EMPTY: String
    get() = ""
```

Usage in this case is just like you've shown:

```
val firstName: String = String.EMPTY
```

(This is mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#companion-object-extensions).)

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what i looked for. Can you share how you organize Companion and Extension in project? Do you use something like Utils classes (files) or something else?

Comment: Really, that's all up to you. I usually have a package for `extensions` or `util.extensions`, and within that I place extensions grouped per the type they extend in files with that type's name, as top level constructs. All up to personal preference though.